# How select the text of a editable node in a tree?

Tags: extjs

I need some help here.

The target is select all text when i create a new node in a tree panel. The node is editable.

First, I have a Tree panel whit a editable column:

```
      columns: [{
            xtype: 'treecolumn',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            text: 'name',
            flex: 1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield'
            }
        }],
```

Secondly i have a button "create" for create a new node:

```
      buttons: [{
            text: 'create',
            handler: function() {

                var selectionArray = treePanel.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
                var selectedNode = selectionArray[0];

                treePanel.setLoading(true);

                setTimeout(function() {

                    treePanel.setLoading(false);

                    var model = Ext.create('Item', {
                        id: 8,
                        parent: 4,
                        name: 'New Item 8',
                        leaf: true
                    });

                    selectedNode.appendChild(model);
                    treePanel.getSelectionModel().select(model);

                    var selectionArray = treePanel.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
                    var node = selectionArray[0];
                    cellEditingPlugin.startEdit(node, 0);

                    // how i can select all text un Node created?
                    node.selectText();

                }, 1000);
            }
        }],
```

Then when i create a new Node, i need select all text of editable node. But i cant get it.

I want this:

[image]

The complete code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2jzAk/2/

Thanks.

Comment: var selectedText = selectedNode.get('name') should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `selectOnFocus:true` to your column editor config.